# cannot setup remote platform for Raspberry Pi B+ on Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying setup the remote platform so that I can develop using Netbeans 8.0.2. If followed the instructions given [here](http://jaxenter.com/how-to-deploy-debug-and-profile-java-on-the-raspberry-pi-2-108008.html) as the author referred me to (minus `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk` because Raspbian already comes with java 8), but when I click **Finish**, I receive this error:

```
Could not connect to remote Java SE Platform. Please check your settings.
```

Nothing was wrong with my settings. I had the right host, username, password,

The status bar temporarily showed this:

```
build connecting to remote java SE platform (connect-ssh-password) failed
```

And in the notifications for Netbeans, this appeared after connecting:

```
cmd : cd '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/'; '/home/pi/jre//bin/java' -jar org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seembedded-probe.jar platform.properties
bash: line 1: 15453 Illegal instruction     '/home/pi/jre//bin/java' -jar org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seembedded-probe.jar platform.properties
    C:\Users\Foo Bar 2\AppData\Local\Temp\antScript6209826919581247088.xml:65: Remote command failed with exit status 132
```

My EJDK location is `C:\pi\ejdk1.8.0_06`

**Any suggestions as to what may be wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem.
After reading some of the latest messages from Geertjan at this site :
https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/youtube_ejdk_raspberry_pi_and

I set the Remote JRE path to path of the jdk on my RPI:
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt 
And did NOT click the Create button - but just Finish.
Then it created my remote platform.

hopes it gets you further :)